# Opening multiple sites on the browser tabs with window.open

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and need to open two new tabs pointing to 2 web sites. For example: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com)

It works only if I put one site in there

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

but not when both lines

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
window.open("https://www.yahoo.com");
```

Can you tell me what i need to do to be able to open both sites?

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("btnAsync").addEventListener('click', makeRequest);

  function makeRequest() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Initiatlization of XMLHttpRequest
    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert(' Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
          alert(httpRequest.responseText);
        } else {
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }
      }
    };

    window.open("https://www.google.com");
    window.open("https://www.yahoo.com");
  }
})();
```

```html
<button id="btnAsync" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I run your code. Both sites opened. But before it opens browser blocked popup window so i had to allow it to open. Try your code. And dont forget to allow popup after pressing button.

Answer (score 1):

In the bad old days, it was common for malicious websites to [fork bomb](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/12492) browsers by triggering an infinite loop of new windows.

They implemented protection against this by allowing new windows (and tabs) to be opened only when the function was triggered by a user event (e.g. a click but not a page load) **and** restricting this to opening a single window.

**Some** browsers may prompt the user to allow an additional window to open, but there is no way for a website to simply bypass this important security feature.